# What is difference between EqualTo() and EquivalentTo() in NUnit?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, nunit, nunit-2.5

When I have a `Dictionary<string, int> actual` and then create a completely new `Dictionary<string, int> expected` with the same values as actual.

- Calling `Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(expected));` makes the test pass.
- When using `Assert.That(actual, Is.EquivalentTo(expected));` the test doesn't pass.

What is the difference between `EqualTo()` and `EquivalentTo()`?

Edit:

The message of the exception when the test doesn't pass is as follows:

```
Zoozle.Tests.Unit.PredictionTests.ReturnsDriversSelectedMoreThanOnceAndTheirPositions:
Expected: equivalent to < [Michael Schumacher, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]] >
But was:  < [Michael Schumacher, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]] >
```

My code looks like this:

```
[Test]
public void ReturnsDriversSelectedMoreThanOnceAndTheirPositions()
{
    //arrange
    Prediction prediction = new Prediction();

    Dictionary<string, List<int>> expected = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>()
    {
        { "Michael Schumacher", new List<int> { 1, 2 } }
    };

    //act
    var actual = prediction.CheckForDriversSelectedMoreThanOnce();

    //assert
    //Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(expected));
    Assert.That(actual, Is.EquivalentTo(expected));
}

public Dictionary<string, List<int>> CheckForDriversSelectedMoreThanOnce()
{
    Dictionary<string, List<int>> expected = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
    expected.Add("Michael Schumacher", new List<int> { 1, 2 });

    return expected;
}
```

Comment: `Assert.That()` throws an exception + gives detailed message what was wrong. Please post that.

Comment: I don't think I follow you. Assert.That() throws exception? It's the new nunit syntax - I didn't think it would do anything different than the old model. Aside from that, where do you want me to place this?

Comment: He wants you to add NUnit's output when the test fails to the question.

Comment: If assert fails, it throw the appropriate exception. Does it not?

Comment: Okay, got it - code and exception added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both works for me:

```
var actual = new Dictionary<string, int> { { "1", 1 }, { "2", 2 } };
var expected = new Dictionary<string, int> { { "1", 1 }, { "2", 2 } };

Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(expected)); // passed
Assert.That(actual, Is.EquivalentTo(expected)); // passed
```

---

- `Is.EqualTo()` inside NUnit, if both objects are `ICollection`, uses `CollectionsEqual(x,y)` which iterates both to find the difference. I guess it's equal to `Enumerable.SequenceEqual(x,y)`
- `Is.EquivalentTo` does this immediate because support sequences only: `EquivalentTo(IEnumerable)`

Comment: You are completely right, the problem with me is that in my dictionary I have a string as a key and another collection, a list, to hold integers as value. It's at that point that EquivalentTo throws an exception.

Comment: @Garth: As you already pointed the reason in `List<int>`. `CollectionsEqual` simultaneously iterates over both collections to compare, and because values are collections to, NUnit has no ability to compare it propeprly, and just calls `list1.Equals(list2)` which performs comparison by references, which fails.

Comment: This failing is for the `EquivalentTo()`, right? Because the `EqualTo()` seems to work just fine -> When I change a value in the list it picks it up just fine that something is not correct.

Comment: @Garth: Yes, I was talking about `EquivalentTo()`. So use it for one-level-only collections, not for nested.

Answer (score 18):

The question title forces me to state the following:

For enumerations, `Is.EquivalentTo()` does the comparison allowing any order of the elements.
In contrast, `Is.EqualTo()` takes into account the exact order of the elements, like `Enumerable.SequenceEqual()` does.

However, in your case, there is no issue with ordering. The main point here is that `Is.EqualTo()` has extra code for dictionary comparison, as stated [here](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=equalConstraint&r=2.5.8).

Not so `Is.EquivalentTo()`. In your example, it will compare values of type `KeyValuePair<string,List<int>>` for equality, using `object.Equals()`. Since the dictionary values are of reference type `List<int>`, reference equality is used for comparing them.

If you modify your example such that the List {1, 2} is only instantiated once and used in both dictionaries, `Is.EquivalentTo()` will succeed.